# c# struct/class initilaze a Arraylist

Tags: c#, struct, initialization, arraylist

I have this code :

```
 public struct SmartFilter
    {
        public int from, to;
        public ArrayList collect  = new ArrayList();                 
        public long bit;            
    }
```

i get error :

> cannot have instance field
>   initializers in structs

i try different way to get over this error without success,

how to have a array list in struct / class?

Comment: The error message you get from the compiler seems pretty clear to me... I think you could have solved this one on your own.

Comment: *why* is it a struct? Without a **very** good reason, that is an error

Comment: (for info, the reason you can't have a field initializer on a struct is that the default constructor doesn't really exist and even if it did, it would not be guaranteed to run...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems there:

- having a mutable struct - just evil
- having public fields
- using `ArrayList`

none of these is helping you...

with a `class` the initializer would work fine

with a property you could do lazy init:

```
public ArrayList Collect {
    get { return collect ?? (collect = new ArrayList()); }
}
```

I would refactor to:

```
public class SmartFilter
{
    public int From  {get;set;}
    public int To  {get;set;}
    private List<SomeKnownType> collect  = new List<SomeKnownType>();
    public List<SomeKnownType> Collect { get { return collect; } }
    public long Bit {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Why is having a mutable struct just evil? If the thing you are working is a value object, isn't it just fine to use a struct?

Comment: @Tomas the number of bugs introduced by people not fully appreciating the copy semantics of structs is staggering, and the issues with losing changes etc is huge. Structs *can* be used successfully as mutable entities, but as the exception rather than the rule - it forces a very different programming style (either lots of `ref`, or accessing directly in an array - not a list or similar). I use them myself very occasionally. But the **vast majority** of mutable structs I see are used inappropriately, and almost always are the underlying cause of the bug that I've been summoned to investigate.

Comment: I rarely use structs just as you, and I agree with that they cause a lot of pain since a lot of developers don't know how to deal with them. But saying that they are "just evil" is pretty hard :).

Answer (score 3):

Eh, I'll let the guys with bigger brains than me explain why, but you can't do that. :)  However you could do this...

```
class NotAStruct
{
    public int from, to;
    public ArrayList collect = new ArrayList();
    public long bit;   
}
```

...or this...

```
struct Blah
{
    ArrayList doh;
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        doh = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

But neither is a good idea, as pointed out by several other people.

Comment: *"You can't have an ArrayList in a struct."*  -1 This is completely and utterly incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, that was worded poorly. I'll rephrase.

Comment: @cdhowie, Yeah, I think my fingers were going faster than my brain was. :-)

Comment: @Haim, Your welcome, but make sure you heed the advice in the other answers.

Comment: Even though it works, public variables is not that nice. It's a small difference to public properties, but with public properties you get some more "control"

Answer (score 2):

You should make a class of it, I wouldn't keep an `ArrayList` in a struct since struct should be used for simple data. Regarding the error you have I think you just can remove the `new ArrayList();` and it should work.

I wrote this and it works just fine:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int intVal;
    public ArrayList listVal;
    public bool boolVal;
}
```

However, I really thing you should use a class instead; that is, use this instead:

```
public class MyClass    {
    public int IntVal {get; set;}
    public ArrayList ListVal {get; set;}
    public bool BoolVal {get; set;}
}
```